# Why Louis care about the time when Clement had been working with Skarssen?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-international

In *The International (2009)*, According to gendarmerie's accident report, Louis claims Clement had been working with Skarssen since 10 AM the day he was killed.

But Skarssen's lawyer says Clement had been working with Skarssen since 6PM.

So Why Louis caring so much about the time?